# change Text of several labels located on a Tab control using loop in C#

Tags: c#, label, tabcontrol, tabpage

I have a windows form project ( Net 4) in C#, and I want to change all of my label.Texts  in a loop. but my labels are in a Tabcontrol (in tabpage 4) and i don't know what to do. my labels name are label1 label2 and so.. until label 100.

Comment: Why so many labels?

Comment: Get the `TabPage` for page 4 from the `TabPages` property of the `TabControl`. Then get the Controls collection from the `TabPage`. You can loop on the `Controls` collection and look for labels. Modify each label based on its name.

Comment: can you complete this for me? @JimRhodes
tabPage4.Controls.Find("label" + i.ToString()+".Text", true) ;

Comment: @maccettura do you suggest something else? i'm amatur in C#.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: @JimRhodes No, I'm trying to do this for myself. But I rather to do this in this way, If it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this to loop through the controls and set the label text based on the number in the name.

```
foreach ( Control ctrl in tabPage4.Controls )
{
  if ( ctrl.GetType().Equals(typeof(Label)) )
  {
    string strName = ctrl.Name;
    if ( strName.StartsWith("label", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) )
    {
      string strNum = strName.Substring(5);
      int iIndex;
      if ( int.TryParse(strNum, out iIndex) )
      {
        ctrl.Text = "your text";
      }
    }
  }
}
```